# MEAN : How can I keep the public folder on a remote machine?

Tags: mean-stack, meanjs

I need to separate the client files and keep them on a different machine for load balancing. I'm wondering if there is a standard way to do it. So far I've tried changing the urls to that of the remote machine. But there are too many configurations done assuming public folder on local.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to do it this way:
1. Minify and concat all frontend(angular) js files +bower components(libs) into single frontend.js
2. Do the same with css files
3. You can keep your folder structure from meanjs (diectory public), with only html files and just put your frontend.js and frontend.css in top of it. Now you have to include only these 2 files in backend. All frontend templates should work propely, because meanjs uses paths from root directory, like  modules/xyz/views/list-xyz.client.view.html <- nothing changed there.
4. You can automate this procedures with gulp or grunt tasks.